# How can I superscript a single character throughout my site?

Tags: web-development

Finishing up development work for a client and they have a late request to superscript every occurrence of the &reg character throughout the site. I merely get by with CSS, but not even sure CSS provides the best solution here. how can I make a global change to every occurrence of a single character in the site copy without going back and adding tags everywhere?

if the best solution *does* involve inserting a span or other tag I'm thinking it could be accomplished with a database query (all the copy is wired up to a CMS).

Answer (score 2):

If the content is in a database you should be able to replace all `&reg;` in their content with one query (assuming it is all in one table). It would look like this (assuming MySQL):

```
UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = REPLACE(fieldname, '&reg;', '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
```

**edit**

I just used the `<sup>` tag instead of CSS. You can obviously choose which method you prefer.

Comment: Hmm.. should it be `&reg;` and not just `&reg` ?

Comment: @dvn66 If modifying the database is not an option or the CMS table structure proves unfathomable, there are also some JavaScript solutions in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703961/css-superscript-registration-trademark

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, there should be a semicolon at the end. Adding it now.

Comment: thank you very much for the replies, I'll implement a solution and report back with any useful findings.